# can I add a uiprogressbar to a uibutton

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to know if it is possible to subclass UIButton someway to add another component to it such as a preloader or progress indicator.

In pseudo code what I have in mind is something like the following.

```
UIButtonWithProgress *button =[[UIButtonWithProgress alloc]init]

[button.progressbar setProgress:50%]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS the class for a progress bar is *UIProgressView*. If you really wanted to add a *UIButton* to a *UIProgressBar* (as in the question title). Then you can use the *UIView* method `addSubView:` For example:

```
UIButtonWithProgress* button = [[UIButtonWithProgress alloc] init];
UIProgressView* progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
[button addSubview:progressView];
progressView.progress = 0.5;
```

I think what you really want to do is create your own UIControl (so you should subclass that instead). You can override the method `drawRect:` to use quartz to draw your own progress bar animation, and the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to detect the user tapping on your custom control, as well as adding any other methods you wish to control the state of the control (such as the progress level).

Note: In my code example I also give an example of correctly setting the progress of the UIProgressBar, just in case you were unclear.

Comment: o.k, I see where you're going. Thanks

Comment: `In my code example I also give an example of **correctly** setting the progress of the UIProgressBar, just in case you were unclear.` Nope. progress takes a float between 0.0 and 1.0